# What's wrong in this HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this table . But the problem is that the last row keeps coming next to the one before it though each one is in a different row . I don't understand  why . I tried to change the width and height but nothing worked . This is the code:

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<table border="1" width="50%">
<tr>
   <th rowspan="2">
     nnnnnnnnnn
   </th>
   <th colspan="2">
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   </th>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbb</td> 
     <td>ccccccccccccc</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
     <td rowspan="2">Un</td>
     <td  rowspan="2">bal blabal blabal blabal blabal blabal </td>
     <td  rowspan="2">xxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td rowspan="2">Deux</td>
     <td  rowspan="2">yyyyyyyyyyy </td>
     <td  rowspan="2">bal blabal blabal blabal blabal</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how I want the table to look: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVP3B.png)

Comment: Why any `rowspan` on the lower rows at all?!

Comment: add expected output ... remove all rowspan will solve your problem is guess

Comment: This is an useful link to have saved: [HTML Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables). Maybe it helps you other times.

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<table border="1" width="50%">
<tr>
   <th rowspan="2">
     nnnnnnnnnn
   </th>
   <th colspan="2">
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   </th>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbb</td> 
     <td colspan="2">ccccccccccccc</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Un</td>
     <td>bal blabal blabal blabal blabal blabal </td>
     <td>xxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Deux</td>
     <td>yyyyyyyyyyy </td>
     <td>bal blabal blabal blabal blabal</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Explain* the problem and solution please?

Comment: @deceze remove rowspan and add colspan 2,  2nd title because the column is 3

Comment: Onkar Musale yes I did and thank you for mentioning this ^^

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<table border="1" width="50%">
<tr>
   <th rowspan="2">
     nnnnnnnnnn
   </th>
   <th colspan="4">
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   </th>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td colspan="2">bbbbbbbbbbbbb</td> 
     <td colspan="2">ccccccccccccc</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
     <td rowspan="1">Un</td>
     <td  colspan="2">bal blabal blabal blabal blabal blabal </td>
     <td  colspan="2">xxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td rowspan="1">Deux</td>
     <td  colspan="2">yyyyyyyyyyy </td>
     <td  colspan="2">bal blabal blabal blabal blabal</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Explain* the problem and solution please?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the rowspan for the 2 rows will give you a table as shown in the example.

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<table border="1" width="50%">
<tr>
   <th rowspan="2">
     nnnnnnnnnn
   </th>
   <th colspan="2">
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   </th>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbb</td> 
     <td>ccccccccccccc</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Un</td>
     <td>bal blabal blabal blabal blabal blabal </td>
     <td>xxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Deux</td>
     <td>yyyyyyyyyyy </td>
     <td>bal blabal blabal blabal blabal</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you .But how can you please explain why it didn't work with rowspan="2" ?

Comment: Well, you're telling the row to span over 2 rows, but it's only one row.

Comment: Aha ! now I understand  I was thinking that but by adding rowspan="2"  the height of the row will increase . thanks !

Comment: Feel free to upvote / accept if it helped/solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basic HTML Table Design

```css
tr {
  height: 80px;
}

table,tr,th,td{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">
        nnnnnnnnnn
      </th>
      <th colspan="5">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">bbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
      <td colspan="2">ccccccccccccc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">Un</td>
      <td colspan="2">bal blabal blabal blabal blabal blabal </td>
      <td colspan="2">xxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">Deux</td>
      <td colspan="2">yyyyyyyyyyy </td>
      <td colspan="2">bal blabal blabal blabal blabal</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question:)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like the picture you've posted, with tables. But I would recommand to use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```html
<html>
<body>
  <table border="1" width="50%">
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">
        nnnnnnnnnn
      </th>
      <th colspan="4">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbb asdasd</td>
      <td>ccccccccccccc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Un</td>
      <td>bal blabal blabal blabal </td>
      <td>xxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Deux</td>
      <td>yyyyyyyyyyy </td>
      <td>bal blabal blabal blabal</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question ^^